# Snapshot feature directly through SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I was wondering if it's possible to run a snap through SQL for certain reports? We currently have them timed to refresh on a schedule, but occasionally a couple reports in a schedule do not refresh. Ex. 100 reports are scheduled to refresh daily at 10:00 AM, 90 out of those 100 reports refresh properly. I have a query to pull the reports that did not refresh (RDL names, scheduled times, etc), but I was wondering if there was a SQL query to run a re-snap directly on those reports only?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ReportSchedule table, the ScheduleID is the name of a SQL Server Agent job. You can loop through these ScheduleIDs in a cursor and exexute the corresponding jobs using

```
DECLARE @Jobname varchar(36) = @ScheduleID;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @Jobname;
```

Or you can inspect such a job to find the TSQL that does the snapshot.